# Display a list of subcategories a post belongs to

Tags: categories

I have this code:

```
<?php
// List subcategories of category '4'
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=4'); 
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo sprintf(' <a href="%s">%s</a> <span class="sep">•</span>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
?>
```

This code retrieves a list of subcategories from category id 4. I have added this code in post loop(`have_posts()`). It is showing all tagged subcategories from that category on  every [post's box](http://prntscr.com/3r32oy).

What I want is to just show the subcategories from the category 4, which is tagged in that post. It shouldn't show all the subcategories from all categories tagged for all the posts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your english is a bit broken, making it hard to understand. Do you just want to show posts from category 4 on the homepage?

Comment: @PieterGoosen Sorry for my bad english. i am updated the question. my problem is, It showing all the subcategories tagged in for all posts. i just want to show only the subcategories tagged for that post. see this (http://prntscr.com/3r32oy). it is showing all subcategories tagged in for all posts. i just want to show only the subcategories tagged for that post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function I've recently used (modified version of the code found in the codex) to display a list of the categories a post is attached to.

This function first gets the parent category to which the post belong, and that info is then fed back into [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) to remove the parent category and to get a list of the child categories belonging to that parent

```
<?php 
$taxonomy = 'category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';
$categories = get_the_category();
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent;

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&child_of=' . $parentid . '&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome!!. Thanks, it works like magic. i have been search this for last few days. (Y)

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you should remove the ampersand (which is used to concatenate multiple arguments) and use `parent` instead of `child_of`, so that only subcategories (and not deeper-nested categories) are listed:

```
$subcategories = get_categories( 'parent=4' );
```

Comment: dude my problem was not showing up the nested categories. my problem was it is showing all the subcategories tagged in for all posts. i just want to show only the subcategories tagged for that post.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean! There's a friendlier way to put that :-). In that case, Peter seems to have answered your question! I would suggest trying to formulate your questions a bit clearer next time.

Comment: thanks for your help. @Pieter Goosen's answer helped and it works awesome